# How to get some objects to move randomly in a space lets say a grid of [-5,5]

Tags: matlab

I need to move some objects lets say 50  in a space (i.e a grid of [-5,5]) and making sure that if the grid is divided into 100 portions most of the portions (90% or more) are once visited by any object

constraints :

object should move in random directions in the grid changing their velocities frequently (change speed and direction in each iteration)

I was thinking of bouncing balls ( BUT moving in random directions even if not hit by anything in space, not they way a real ball moves) , if we could leave them into space in different positions with different forces and each time they hit each other (or getting closer to a specific distance ) they move to different directions with different speed  and could give us a result near to 90% hit of portions in the grid .

I also need to make sure objects are not getting out of grid ( could make lb and ub limits and get them back in case they try to leave the grid)

My code is different from the idea I have written above ...

```
 ux = 1;  
 uy = 15;
 g = 9.81;
 t = 0; x(1) = 0; 
 y(1) = 0;  
 tf = 2.0 * uy / g; % time of flight back to the ground
 dt = tf / 20; % time increment - taking 20 steps  
 while t < tf
 t = t + dt;     
 if((uy - 0.5 * g * t) * t >= 0)
 x(end + 1) = ux * t;           
y(end + 1) = (uy - 0.5 * g * t) * t;
 end      
end    
plot(x,y)
```

this code makes the ball to go with Newton's law which is not the case
Bottom line i just need to be able to visit many portions of grid in a short time so this is why i want the objects to moves in a chaotic way in the space in a random manner (each time running the code i need different result so it needs to be random path) and to get a better result i could make the objects bounce to different directions if they hit or visit each other in the same portions , this probably give me a better result .

Comment: Please provide the code, you have so far.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex). You'll get much better help if you do. Again, welcome.

Comment: Try editing your question rather than posting unformatted code in a comment.